# How to collect data from a registration form which consists of two activities and submit to MySQL database

Tags: android, mysql

I'm developing an app, and I have a user registration form which is very long.
Since the registration form is long, I decided to use multiple activities for it, so the user will have to click on continue button to access the next part of the form.

The challenge I am facing is collecting the other information from previous activities and submitting it as one thing to MySQL database.
Can anyone show me how to collect the data from the form which consists of two activities and submit it to the database?

Answer (score 2):

Create a model for all your requirements. For example,

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class RegistrationModel implements Serializable
{
    private String name, age, dob, address, pincode, hobby, profession;

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getDob()
    {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(String dob)
    {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getAddress()
    {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address)
    {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPincode()
    {
        return pincode;
    }

    public void setPincode(String pincode)
    {
        this.pincode = pincode;
    }

    public String getHobby()
    {
        return hobby;
    }

    public void setHobby(String hobby)
    {
        this.hobby = hobby;
    }

    public String getProfession()
    {
        return profession;
    }

    public void setProfession(String profession)
    {
        this.profession = profession;
    }
}
```

In your first activity, when next button is clicked fill the model and pass it to the next activity using serialization.

```
RegistrationModel model = new RegistrationModel();
model.setName("XXX");
model.setAddress("XXX");
// Like this, fill all data in first activity

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Data", model);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in the SecondActivity, get your pre-filled model like this:

```
RegistrationModel model = ((RegistrationModel)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Data"))
```

And continue with the registration.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a good approach to your problem is just use fragments instead of two activities. The main advantaje is that you can swich from one fragment to another easily.

I mean, you can have one main activity that holds the user object. then:

1. Activity shows the first fragment.
2. When user fill the form and push next, the fragment call back the activity with the form data. Use a callback interface for this.
3. Activity instantiate the user variable with data and shows second fragment.
4. When the user fill the second form and push finish, call back the activity with form data. Again you can do this with a callback interface.
5. Finally, the activity add the new data to the user variable and send all the information to database.

From documentation, how to communicate Activity and fragments.

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Example of one fragment:

```
public class HeadlinesFragment extends Fragment {
    OnFormFillesListener mCallback;

    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface OnFormFillesListener {
        public void onFirstForm(String name, String nick ...);

        public void onFSecondForm(String character, int id ...);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
        try {
            mCallback = (OnFormFillesListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFormFillesListener");
        }
    }

    ...

    public void onNext() {
        mCallback.onFirstForm(name, nick ...);
    }

}
```

And the Activity:

```
public static class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements OnFormFillesListener  {

    private User mUser;

    ...

    public void onFirstForm(String name, String nick ...) {
        // instantiate the user
        mUser = new User (name, nick, ...);

        // show second fragment
    }

    public void onFSecondForm(String character, int id ...) {
        // add new data to user
        mUser.setCharacter(character);
        mUser.serId(id);
        ...

        // send User to Database
    }
}
```